# Looking for REST API (s) in google cloud to pull health, cpu load etc information of servers deployed in kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i have a SpringBoot application which is showing helath of all the servers in react charts today. we have some applications(servers) deployed to GCP using Kubernetes. i would like to pull and show health of the servers, number of pods, cpu utilization etc in my spring boot application. i have searched all GKE related REST apis in documentation, how ever i found REST urls at https://container.googleapis.com. but, none of them are seems to help me. please help me find the set of REST api's to fetch the above said heath statistics.

Comment: Google has a product and APIs for monitoring. https://cloud.google.com/monitoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest)

You will find all info you need like [cpu utilization](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp) and other useful metrics

> The "metric type" strings in this table must be prefixed with `actions.googleapis.com/`

- Metric type: `instance/cpu/utilization`:

> *Fractional utilization of allocated CPU on this instance. Values are typically numbers between 0.0 and 1.0 (but some machine types allow bursting above 1.0). Charts display the values as a percentage between 0% and 100% (or more). This metric is reported by the hypervisor for the VM and can differ from `agent.googleapis.com/cpu/utilization`, which is reported from inside the VM. Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 240 seconds.
> instance_name: The name of the VM instance*

---

#### Creating the GET request

@Raj: This is not the url for the get request, check [this tutorial](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-gce-metrics/), you want to format your get request the following way (change parameters depending on your own values):

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"\
 "https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/{{YOUR_PROJECT}}/timeSeries/?filter=metric.type+%3D+%22compute.googleapis.com%2Finstance%2Fcpu%2Futilization%22&\
interval.endTime=2017-01-30T21%3A45%3A00.000000Z\
&interval.startTime=2017-01-30T21%3A43%3A00.000000Z"
{
  "timeSeries": [
    {
      "metric": {
        "labels": {
          "instance_name": "evan-test"
        },
        "type": "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"
      },
      "resource": {
        "type": "gce_instance",
        "labels": {
          "instance_id": "743374153023006726",
          "zone": "us-east1-d",
          "project_id": "evan-testing"
        }
      },
      "metricKind": "GAUGE",
      "valueType": "DOUBLE",
      "points": [
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2017-01-30T21:44:01.763Z",
            "endTime": "2017-01-30T21:44:01.763Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 0.00097060417263416339
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2017-01-30T21:43:01.763Z",
            "endTime": "2017-01-30T21:43:01.763Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 0.00085122420706227329
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
```

Comment: i have tried invoking agent.googleapis.com/cpu/utilization REST api from Google Developers Rest tool. it returns 404 - the requested url not found message.

Comment: yes, i have tried with 'https' protocol. here is the complete url i have tried, 'uri: 
 https://agent.googleapis.com/cpu/utilization Method: GET'

Comment: see my edit, this url is not where you make the GET request, 404 means "not found" which is different from 403 "Forbidden" like what you will likely get if you try to send this request with the wrong TOKEN and pointing at the wrong instance_id, zone and project_id

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. suggested REST url is working and returning a double value as "unit" : "xx.xx". 
i have below mentioned concens on this solution,
1. this REST url is giving cpu utilization for  a particular instance. is there any api to get list of instances for the given project or location or zone?
2. is there an api for making REST call to retrieve Bearer token?
3. when i try to pass the similar payload to '/cpu/utilization' service, it complains that expected value for query is string value, but object found.